# Launch filterAcceptsRow after a displacement/zoom of a qml map is stabilized

Tags: qt, location, qml

On a QML Map, using "onCenterChanged" to capture a user-activated move, the filtering process of the points to be displayed on, starts as soon as the move is initiated.

Given the large number of data to be processed during this operation, I want it to begin only after the total stabilization of the Map (stop sliding/zooming, left mouse button released and mouse wheel inactive).

here is a snippet of the QML Map

```
Map {
    id: mainMap
    anchors.centerIn: parent;
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: Plugin {name: "osm"}
    center: startingPoint
    zoomLevel: 4.5

    onCenterChanged: {
        updateBoundingBox()
    }

    MapItemView {
        id:viewPointOnMap
        model: navaidsFilter
        delegate: Marker{}
    }

    onMapReadyChanged: {
        updateBoundingBox()
    }

    function updateBoundingBox(){
        navaidsFilter.bBox = mainMap.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle() //boundingBox
    }

}//Map
```

and the filter snippets :

```
void NavaidsFilter::setBBox(const QGeoRectangle &bbox)
{
    if(m_processedZone.isEmpty()|| !m_processedZone.contains(bbox)){  //First bbox or displacement/zoom out of the previous box
        m_processedZone = bbox;
        m_boundaryZone = bbox;
        invalidateFilter();
    }
}

bool NavaidsFilter::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    if(!m_boundaryZone.isValid()){
        return false;
    }

    QModelIndex ix = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    QGeoCoordinate pos = ix.data(NavaidsModel::PositionRole).value<QGeoCoordinate>();
    return m_boundaryZone.contains(pos);
}
```

How can we achieve this?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with `Map` so I don't know a specific solution. Here are two general solutions that work in many cases:

1. Introduce a property that aggregates all states that are relevant

   ```
   readonly property bool moving: mainMap.gesture.rotationActive
                                  | mainMap.gesture.tiltingActive
                                  | ...`
   ```

   once this property changes to `false` do what is necessary. (`onMovingChanged`)

---

2. Use a `Timer` that you restart, whenever something changes. If for some *ms* nothing changes, let it trigger and do what is necessary.

Comment: Thanks derM. So Itry to use the magGestureArea and add gesture.enabled: true and gesture.acceptedGestures: MapGestureArea.PanGesture in order to use the onPanFinished for initiate update instead of onCenterChanged. However I face this problem : Cannot assign to non-existent property "onPanFinished". Will you have a tip to remove it ?